# Как зациклить получение через ajax и вывод данных

Tags: jquery, json

Знаком с jquery очень слабо
пользуясь костылями в виде гугла составил вот такой код
смысл конструкции - получение данных о клане танков
получаю список участников(их айдишки) - нормально выводит.

[image: json с айдишками участинков]

хочу потом в цикле делать другой запрос, вставляя в конце полученную айдишку.
и распарсить json и получить другие данные

[image: данные участника клана]

но выводит только последнего участника данные.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

что я не так сделал?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var id=177503;
    var emb=1;
    $.ajax({
         url:"http://api.worldoftanks.ru/wgn/clans/info/?application_id=demo&fields=color,created_at,description,creator_id,description,members_count,motto,name,tag,emblems,members.account_id&clan_id="+id,
          type:"get",         
          dataType: 'json',
          //данные уже в json
          success:function(result){ 

                        $('#vi').text('#members  '+ result.data[id].members_count);
            $('#ajaxDiv3').text('Descr  '+ result.data[id].description);
            $('#ajaxDiv4').text('tag  '+ result.data[id].tag);
                $('#ajaxDiv2').text('motto  '+ result.data[id].motto);
                $('#name').text('name '+ result.data[id].name);
                $('#imgson').text('name '+result.data[id].emblems.x64.portal);

           $('#img1').attr({ src: result.data[id].emblems.x64.portal, alt: result.data[id].emblems.x64.portal});

var theDate = new Date(result.data[id].created_at * 1000); 
 $('#viss').text('Updated at  '+ theDate.toLocaleString());

  var dd;            
 var cou=result.data[id].members_count; //количество участников клана

for (var i=0; i<cou; i++) {
   $('#viss').append('<br>ID: '+result.data[id].members[i].account_id ); 
    // получаю айдишку текущего участника
    dd=result.data[id].members[i].account_id;

    $.ajax({
         url:"http://api.worldoftanks.ru/wgn/clans/membersinfo/?application_id=demo&fields=account_name,role_i18n,joined_at&account_id="+dd,
          type:"get",         
          dataType: 'json',
          //данные уже в json
          success:function(result1){ 

                        $('#mmb').append('<br>#role  '+ result1.data[dd].role_i18n);
                        }
                        });
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Вот закинул http://jsfiddle.net/drdead84/y6fyv100/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот более правильный вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/y6fyv100/1/

Я заменил классический цикл на .forEach, так лучше.

*Небольшой совет1: открой консоль.*

*Небольшой совет2: твой код грозит превратиться в упаковку вермишели запросов-колбеков, чтобы этого не произошло стоит изучить такую область jquery как [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) и переписать свой код исходя из полученных знаний.*

Comment: Спасибо! я новичок в джаве - больше на дельфях)

Comment: я так понял $.Deferred  - это аналог try except в дельфях? обработка ошибок.

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк нет. поищи на хабре